# How to use Terminal to send keystrokes?

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

Is there a way for Terminal to simulate pressing multiple keys at once? For example, Shift+Ctrl+R?

I am `ssh`ing into OS X from a Windows client (PuTTY) and am wondering if I need to configure the client or is there a native way for OS X to emulate these commands on the receiving end.

Comment: It is about using terminal to send keyboard shortcuts. Specifically, I need to send ctrl+opt+shift+e. I need to do it without AppleScript, as it is from a Windows computer, using what I assume is some kind of Terminal simulator, or SSH from cmd.

Comment: AppleScript works over SSH using osascript. The below answer is fully functional over SSH providing a GUI is present on the OS X machine.

Answer (score 17):

You can use AppleScript on the Terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using {control down, shift down}'
```

Comment: When I try that, I just get a new line with ">"?

Comment: Is it program specific? For example, if I want to type in "E" into TextEdit, would I type "osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "e" using {shift down}'"?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to type ctrl+opt+shift+e, and I have "osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "e" using {control down, shift down, option down}'" but it tells me "48:55: syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this “"”. (-2740)"

Comment: Keystrokes are entered exactly as they would be if they were manually typed; they're not specific to each application. If you want to enter a keystroke within an application use `osascript -e 'tell application "AppName" to activate'. This will launch the application if it's not already open and also bring it the the foreground (i.e. it's name shows up in the menu bar). You can then use the code @grg provided in his answer above.

Answer (score 7):

the cliclick shell tool is pretty awesome. sends keystrokes, clicks, all sorts of stuff

https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick

Comment: boulder_ruby - an excellent solution, great reference. Are you the `cliclick` author?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh that's a negative, just a nerd obsessed with automation